# Use wp_query after changing database via new wpdb

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to access custom posts from other database using wordpress. To do this i have changed the current `$wpdb` global variable:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );
$wpdb->show_errors();
```

This doesn't show any errors, but when I try to use `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'produtos');
$newloop = new WP_Query($args);
```

I get the following error:

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM WHERE 1=1 AND .post_type = 'produtos' AND (.post_status = 'publish' OR .' at line 1]
>
> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS .ID FROM WHERE 1=1 AND .post_type = 'produtos' AND (.post_status = 'publish' OR .post_author = 1 AND .post_status = 'private') ORDER BY .post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10

---

If i use `$wpdb->get_results()` and `$wpdb->get_var()` functions I can achieve what I want:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type='produtos' AND post_status='publish'");
foreach ($rows as $produto) {
   $id = $produto->ID;
   $title = $produto->post_title;
   $valor = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'preco' AND post_id = $id");
   $url_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = $id AND meta_key='_thumbnail_id'");
}
```

I am looking for an elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Why would you overwrite `$wpdb`? What exactly are you attempting to achieve? What's the bigger picture, that makes it necessary?

Comment: I want to use the post type 'produtos' from the main website in the mobile website (a subdomain with its own wordpress installation).

I read in this [thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100666/how-can-i-connect-to-another-wp-database-and-use-wp-query) that i should overwrite $wpdb because WP_Query uses it.

Comment: I am not sure but your both wordpress is same version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );
```

after creating the wpdb object, you need to set the table names, it's done by calling the `set_prefix() method` it will set up the table names.

```
 set_prefix( $prefix, $set_table_names = true )
```

if you check your sql error. the table names are empty. The default table prefix is  `'wp_'`.

solution:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( $user, $pass, $db, $host );
$wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');

//then rest of your code..
```

Comment: avoid comments like thanks. well, after about 5 straight hours of battling this has solved my problem..thanks, so so so much!

Comment: This isn't working for me! Both databases are on the same server but still does not work! Any suggestions, btw, using the exact same code.